# Circular queue that simply updates the indices

Tags: c++, boost

I need a circular queue for my producer-consumer application. In my case, I have a pre-allocated array of objects (of class A):

```
A mylist[10];
```

Looking at Boost examples, it appears items need to be "pushed" and "popped" into/from the queue.

However, in my case, I am trying to avoid creating a new object each time and pushing it in the queue when I can simply reuse the existing object.

My preference is to simply update the content of the object at the current producer index (and update the index to the next location). Likewise, the consumer uses the contents of the object at the current consumer index (and updates the index to the next location). Essentially, there is no pushing or popping per se.

While I could put together my own implementation, I am wondering if there is already something out there in the STL or Boost that I can use.

Edit: Boost requires me to create a new value each time I push it into the   queue. In my case, I need to add 100+ items per second. Memory allocations  will kill my application. Here is boost pseudo-code to illustrate my problem:

```
class A {
public:
   int x;
};
boost::circular_buffer<A*> list(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   A* p = new A();
   p->x = i;
   list.push_back(p);
}

int val = 100;
while(true) {
   // Set new values at the head of the queue
    A* p = new A();
    p->x = val; val++;
    list.push_back(p);
}
```

As you can see, I would simply like to reuse the objects in the queue instead of creating a new object.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue

Comment: Never mind, you want a circular buffer.

Comment: I looked at boost circular buffer example. I am not sure. It still requires you to "push_back" a value.

Comment: @Peter: true - it does - but (with C++11 and current boost) if you push back a temporary or a value wrapped with `std::move()` it'll move it into the buffer, so it's unlikely to be particularly expensive.  (Obligatory note: it's usually best to get your code working then see if it's too slow; if so use a profiler to work out what to optimise.)

Comment: I have added a pseudo-example to illustrate my point. The memory allocations will kill the performance. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: What is wrong with putting pointers into the circular buffer?

Comment: @Peter The `push_back` function is there to make it compatible with STL containers, and to indicate where in the buffer you're putting your value. In reality, the value is being copied (or moved) into the space which is currently the "back" of the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for [Boost.CircularBuffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html).

This is effectively a preallocated block of elements, with all of the circular logic handled for you.

An example, from the documentation:

```
// Create a circular buffer with a capacity for 3 integers.
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);

// Insert threee elements into the buffer.
cb.push_back(1);
cb.push_back(2);
cb.push_back(3);

int a = cb[0];  // a == 1
int b = cb[1];  // b == 2
int c = cb[2];  // c == 3

// The buffer is full now, so pushing subsequent
// elements will overwrite the front-most elements.

cb.push_back(4);  // Overwrite 1 with 4.
cb.push_back(5);  // Overwrite 2 with 5.

// The buffer now contains 3, 4 and 5.
a = cb[0];  // a == 3
b = cb[1];  // b == 4
c = cb[2];  // c == 5

// Elements can be popped from either the front or the back.
cb.pop_back();  // 5 is removed.
cb.pop_front(); // 3 is removed.

// Leaving only one element with value = 4.
int d = cb[0];  // d == 4
```

For a FIFO  queue-like application, see the [Bounded Circular Buffer Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/circular_buffer/example/circular_buffer_bound_example.cpp).

For your example, you could rely on the move semantics available in C++11 to avoid dynamic memory allocation:

```
class A {
public:
   int x;
   A (int a) : x(a) {}
};
boost::circular_buffer<A> list(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   list.push_back(A (i));
}

int val = 100;
while(true) {
   // Set new values at the head of the queue
    list.push_back(A (val++));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have edited my original post to include an example of the problem I am running into. I am thinking Boost.CircularBuffer may not help me.